# Не работает https

Tags: apache, ssl, https

Закончился ssl сертификат. При попытке сгенерировать LetsEncrypt выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка генерации сертификата. Домен должен быть привязан!
>   Необходимо добавить А запись с айпи сервера для домена

Но самое удивительное то что при подключении http выдает нормальную страницу сайта, а при попытке подключения по https не выдает ошибку "что злоумышленники  могут похитить ваши данные" а отдает страницу по умолчанию:

> Данный сервер управляется панелью управления BrainyCP. Если вы ожидаете увидеть сайт, то возможно вы:
>   1) не добавили доменное имя в раздел Сайты;
>   2) не очистили кеш Вашего браузера;
>   3) привязали домен к неверному айпи адресу.

Сайт стоит на VDS хостинге, панель управления BrainyCP, OS - CentOS, CMS - ocStore, Веб сервер - Apache

В чем может быть проблема? Если мало информации то я уточню.

Comment: нужно смотреть в BrainyCP как настраивать  ssl

Comment: что указано в разделе Сервер имен в панели НеймСерверы BrainyCP?